# How to sum the number in excel using formula

Tags: excel

it is a very simple question if anybody had a idea about the excel formulas please share your ideas with me.
I had a Excel Sheet I wants to add the 10 numbers for this i just use the formula =sum(A1:A10) in the cell A11 so cell A11 had the Total of 10 numbers my issue  i wants to add the 10 numbers starts from A1:A10 the Total number must be displayed in A10 cell itself  if i use the formula in the cell A10 = sum(A1:A10) it does not work 
thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't make sense, you would get into infinite recursion.

Say you got 1 in each of the fields, then A10 would end up being 10, but then A10 was changed so it would end up being 19 and then it was changed again etc etc

Comment: sorry ,i think i am fail to explain my question clearly that is i am populating student mark data from Access to Excel using Vba  My DB has a student detail ,5 subject marks,its total,if i populate the data in the excel .cell A1 to A4 containg the student detail Cell A5 containt the Subject 1 mark ,A6 subject 2 mark A7 contain subjeck 3 ...... A10 contain its total.
Just i wants to add the formula in cell A10. A10 Already contain the total mark if i again change the values in the Marks (A5:A9) it must be updated with the existing total mark in the cell A10

Comment: @raam: Sorry, I'm afraid I still don't understand. I suggest updating your question where it's easier to format your text and maybe you could try to illustrate with a screenshot or creating some kind of graphics.

Answer (score 1):

@Krusaint - Actually, I think the contents of A10 should be "=sum(A5:A9)" (without the quotes)

Comment: yes, now i using this formula , but my question is A10 already had a value. if i enter the formula in the cell A10  means that value will be removed automatically. 
is it possible to add existing value in the A10 cell

Comment: @Raam - It sounds like A5:A9 have individual marks, and A10 has a running total (that includes marks not listed in A5:A9). 

The immediate solution (proposed by most everyone here), is to add A10 to the individual marks (as an interim sub-total) and place the result in another cell (i.e. A11).

Unfortunately, there isn't a way for you do add the value of a cell and still have it be part of the summation - as pointed out by @ho1.

Why must the total be in A10, and what is the current value in that cell represent? Can that information be calculated on the fly instead of using the value in A10?

Comment: thanks for your time @Robert ,In The Excel Cells A5 : A9 i am populate the data from the MS access If i am insert the formula  = SUM(A5:A9) in the cell A10.It just display 0 in that particular cell , till I change the value in that Range (A5:A9) is there is any way to resolve this, please guide me i tried to solve this issue

Comment: @Raam - that seems quite odd. I tried it using the following values in A5:A9... {1,2,3,4,5}. In A10=SUM(A5:A9), and that correctly gives me a sum of 15. I also set the formatting on A5:A9 to 'Text', to see if maybe that ruined the summation, but it still works. Can you provide the A5:A9 values that are returning a sum of 0?

Answer (score 0):

Delete value in cell A10. Put "=sum(A6:A9)" without quotes in A10.

Answer (score 0):

If for example, the original value in A10 was 97, then do this:
`=SUM(A5:A9)+97`